# Python GTK+ 3: Accessing MenuButton from Popover?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I'm new to GTK+ programming, and I want to do the following: I have a MenuButton with a Popover. The Popover has a Button inside. After I click the inside button, I want to be able to access the MenuButton somehow. Here is an example of what I mean:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class PopoverWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="my window")

        outerbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.add(outerbox)

        self.popover = Gtk.Popover()
        
        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Item 1")
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)
        vbox.pack_start(self.button, False, True, 10)
        vbox.show_all()
        self.popover.add(vbox)
        self.popover.set_position(Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM)

        menu_button = Gtk.MenuButton(label="Click Me", popover=self.popover)
        outerbox.pack_start(menu_button, False, True, 0)

    def on_button_clicked(self, button):
        # how to access the menu_button?

win = PopoverWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Inside `on_button_clicked`, I don't know how to access `menu_button` anymore. I can't call `button.get_parent()`, `button.get_parent().get_parent()`, etc., because the popover is not a child of `menu_button`.

I should also say that changing `menu_button` to `self.menu_button` is not an option for me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "I should also say that changing menu_button to self.menu_button is not an option for me" → Why is this the case?

Comment: So I have a ListBox, and the ListBox contains a variable/dynamic number of rows. Each row has a MenuButton/Popover, and when I access a Popover I would like to know the index of the ListBox row.

Comment: In that case, you don't want to use `self.popover` or `self.button` either.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I shouldn't be using `self` for popover and button. But to my point, is there a way of accessing the specific menubutton object from the popover?

Comment: You could write a custom `Popover` class that has a `self.menu_button` variable. That would probably be the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Widget` that a `Popover` is placed relative to with [`Popover.get_relative_to()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Popover.html#Gtk.Popover.get_relative_to).

I'm not 100% sure if this is necessary (`MenuButton` might already do that), but you'd likely want to explicitly pass the `menu_button` to [the `Popover.new()` constructor](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Popover.html#Gtk.Popover.new), like

```
Popover.new(menu_button)
```

or to [`Popover.set_relative_to()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Popover.html#Gtk.Popover.set_relative_to), like

```
popover.set_relative_to(menu_button)
```

Comment: I might add, at this point it *would* make sense to subclass from `MenuButton` or `Popover` and handle popover item events in that class.